# buttons that shown in design tab aren't visible in emulator

Tags: android-studio

I want to make simple login form. I've tried to add "NEXT" and "REGISTER" buttons. I can see them in the design tab, but can't in emulator. Moreover, i tried to add some extra buttons to see it works. It looks like that: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUstO.png)

Here is my code: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/735240658884886558/1026712117761544233/message.txt

i've also tried to add some text views. They are visible

Comment: remove magin start from these button Relative Layout, you have given hardcoded margin which is sliding you relative layout out of sceen

Comment: it did not work